# determine instance of the web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have several WCF web services.  They all run in the same AppDomain and share various assemblies.  From any method in any assembly how can I determine the particular instance of the web service class that is calling it? (i.e., not the immediate method that calls it, but the web service that it is running in)

Actually I just need the type of the web service class, not the particular instance, but if I have the instance I can get the type.  I haven't found anyone else asking this question, so either I am approaching it wrong or I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: i m not sure my answer helpes you or not but this is the feature in new c# version

Comment: Have you looked at OperationContext.Current?

Comment: @IanGilroy not yet.  Looks like I might be able to use OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.ContractName though!

Comment: I think WCF will flow the operation context across threads that it introduces; if you schedule work on other threads yourself then I guess you'll need to pass the context across if you need it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have several WCF web services. They all run in the same AppDomain
>   and share various assemblies. From any method in any assembly how can
>   I determine the particular instance of the web service class that is
>   calling it?

`OperationContext.Current.Host` gets the `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` for the current service object.  So `OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Name` returns the name of the service.

On initialization of web service, an override of `ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost` could set a delegate (to be called throughout a code-base) that will provide the name of the service according to  `OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Name`.